# how to insert more one single-choice questions in the same exercise

Tags: r-exams

I would like to use the R package 'exams' with my class and do automatic correction through scanning. For this reason, I have decided to consider only single-choice questions.

I would like to insert more than just one single-choice question in the same exercise. Apparently, this can be done only using `\extype{cloze}`. Is this right? I found out that only a unique begin/end pair for "question" is allowed and so is for "answerlist". 
So, I have created an Rnw file whose content is:

```
\begin{question}

Choose between:
\begin{aswerlist}
\item a
\item b
\item c
\item d 
\item e 
\item f
\item a1
\item b1
\item c1
\item d1
\item e1 
\item f1
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
The right answers are:
<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
soluz1 = c(1,rep(0,5)) 
soluz2 = c(1,rep(0,5))
soluz=c(soluz1,soluz2)
answerlist(ifelse(soluz, "True", "False"))
@

\end{solution}

%% \exname{prova}
%% \extype{cloze}
%% \exsolution{\Sexpr{mchoice2string(soluz1)}|mchoice2string(soluz2)}}
%% \exclozetype{schoice|schoice}
%% \exshuffle{5}
```

but I am delivered an error message:

> Error in extract_environment(question, "answerlist", value = FALSE, markup = markup) : 
>     no unique begin/end pair for‘answerlist’found

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, the question formatting is correct but there are two small glitches:

1. In the third line the code says `\begin{aswerlist}` instead of `\begin{answerlist}`. Note the missing `n`! This is what triggers the error message about the begin/end pairs of answerlist not matching.
2. The `mchoice2string(soluz2)` in the `\exsolution{}` lacks `\Sexpr{}` so that the code is evaluated in R.

Further comments:

- In learning management systems like Moodle, such cloze exercises are easy to administer. Then using a combined `cloze` rather than separate `schoice` questions may be appealing.
- However, some learning management systems (like Canvas or Blackboard) do not support `cloze` questions. Also, in written exams via the NOPS system `schoice` is easy to use but `cloze` is not supported.

Hence I would consider carefully which implementation strategy works better for you.

A final tip for debugging: Running `xweave("myexercise.Rnw")` produces a .tex file that might be useful to inspect for potential problems.